# How to fix apps containing an unsafe implementation of 'TrustManager'?

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016,I removed the code that related to `TrustManager`,but still google play rejected me. why this happen, how to solve?

Comment: My workmate solved this problem.  build the apk
 with proguard,then look at the dump file,find some lib use the Trustmanager,and remove them.finally passed

Comment: Do you see the vulnerable class name listed on the developer console?

Comment: cannot see the class name on the developer console

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue. Which dump file I need to check?